# How do you display images one after the other

Tags: objective-c

I am currently iterating through a list and based on the condition of the element I would like to display one of two images. This works fine but how do i put a pause in between displaying the image. I have tried using:

```
for(
   ...
   [myView addSubview:myImage]
   sleep(1)
   ...
)
```

after each check but this for some reason waits for the end of the function before displaying any of the images.

Does anyone what the cause of this is and how to get around it?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *imageArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:image1, image2, imageN, nil];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
imageView.animationImages = imageArray;
imageView.animationDuration = [imageArray count]*3;
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[imageView startAnimating];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `sleep()` here since it will block the thread that is updating you UI.

What you could do is call a different method that set the second image:

```
for(
   ...
   [myView addSubview:myImage]
   // schedule the method.
   [myView performSelector:@selector(addSubview:) withObject:mySecondImage afterDelay:1.0f];
   ...
)
```

Comment: I have tried variations of this and Marcos' solution and nothing gives me a pause between displaying each image.

Comment: Define pause? My example will replace the image showing for the `mySecondImage` after 1 second. You might want to increase the delay.

Comment: Sorry, for example i want to create 5 different `UIImageViews` going down the screen each appearing about a second apart.

Comment: The increase the time out on the next `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` or beter yet use the `animationImages` property like in @Giuseppe-Lanza example.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the alpha/visibility of the element to 0.0f/hidden and use an animation block with a delay to display the view. Gain a fancy animation in the process by setting the duration to something bigger than 0 ;-)

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.0
                      delay: 1.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations: ^{
                         myView.alpha = 1.0f;
                     }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to display an image a use "perform after delay":

```
-(void)displayImage {
    [...get the image...]

    [myView addSubview:myImage];

    [self performSelector:@selector(displayImage) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
}
```